# Horizontal layout of divs - which method is best

Tags: javascript, css

There seem to be various methods of creating a horizontal three column div layout:

1. Position: relative/absolute;
2. Float: left/right; with margin: 0 auto; for center div
3. Float: left; for all divs
4. Display table / table-cell

Any thoughts on which is best practice and the advantages/disadvantages of each approach.

Thanks,

Edit1: Example edited to include line heights

Edit2: One requirement which I forgot to mention is that columns should all be of equal height, thanks @LGSon for pointing that out.

Edit3: added new method - 4. Display table / table-cell.  I know this just feels wrong but in the absence of any other working solutions looks like the best option available at the moment.

```html
1. Position: relative/absolute;
<div id="mainContent" style="position: relative; width:95%; margin: 0 auto; background-color: lightGrey;">
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 0%; width: 33%; background-color:blue;">Left<br>line2</div>
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 33.5%; width: 33%; background-color:green;">Middle</div>
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 67%; width: 33%; background-color:yellow;">Right<br>line2</div>
</div>
<br><br><br>

2. Float: left/right; with margin: 0 auto; for center div
<div id="mainContent" style="overflow: hidden; width:95%; margin: 0 auto; background-color: lightGrey;">
 <div style="float:left; width: 33%; background-color:blue;">Left<br>line2</div>
 <div style="float:right; width: 33%; background-color:yellow;">Right<br>line2</div>
 <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 33%; background-color:green;">Middle</div>
</div>
<br>

3. Float: left; for all divs
<div id="mainContent" style="overflow: hidden; height:100%; width:95%; margin: 0 auto; background-color: lightGrey;">
    <div id="left" style="float: left; width:33%; background-color:blue;">Left<br>line2</div>
    <div id="mid" style="float: left; width:33%; background-color:green;">Middle</div>
    <div id="right" style="float: left; width:33%; background-color:yellow;">Right<br>line2</div>
</div>
<br>

 4. Display table / table-cell
<div id="mainContent" style="width:95%; margin: 0 auto; display: table;">
 <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%; background-color:blue;">Left<br>line2</div>
 <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%; background-color:green;">Middle</div>
 <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%; background-color:yellow;"> Right<br>line2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use bootstrap and grids

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: Thanks Simon but looking for pure Javascript solutions, any idea of the actual Javascript behind how bootstrap works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, use `flexbox`, its newest and modern way for layout, the other one's can sometimes be at hand when one simply can't use or solve it with `flexbox`, though that is quite rare.

With `flexbox` you get exactly that, flexibility, and here is a great article about it: [A guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.mainContent {
  display: flex; 
  width:95%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainContent > div {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
.mainContent > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:blue;
}
.mainContent > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:green;
}
.mainContent > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
 <div>Left</div>
 <div>Middle</div>
 <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

---

Update based on comment/question edit

Since equal height is a requirement, it is either the above `flexbox` or the below `display: table` (unless you want to use script or resort to the old *holy grail* concept)

These two offers dynamic content without the need of fixed height and can easily switch between stacked vertically or horizontally, using a media query.

```css
.mainContent {
  display: table; 
  width:95%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainContent > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.mainContent > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:blue;
}
.mainContent > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:green;
}
.mainContent > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
 <div>Left</div>
 <div>Middle</div>
 <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox would be nice but not supported in IE8/9 which accounts for about 7% of users.

Comment: @NickC We need to know more, as in a sample and/or well explained, showing if these columns should be responsive/wrap-able, equal height, from left-2-right, etc. ... when have that we can actually give a proper answer, as the answer to the now given question has to be _it depends..._ in combo with a recommendation

Comment: Hadn't thought about column height but now you come to mention it that is a problem.  All columns should be equal height and only a big as the largest one.

Comment: New method now added using display: table / table-cell.

Comment: @NickC Since you need to support IE8 and/or IE9, `display: table` is the only way doing what you ask properly ... updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's my summary of options:

**Your first example (Position: Absolute) --** I'd steer away from this, as it's by definition unresponsive to different screen widths and devices.

**Second example (Float: [mixed]) --** this one will work, but it takes a lot of hard-coding float values, which will make it difficult to edit later or apply to other layouts with four items per line, for example. Aim for reusability!

**Third example (float: left) --** this definitely works if you want everything left-aligned, but not much else.

I agree with @LGSon; Flexbox is the way to go, unless you want to use Bootstrap or a similar framework with a grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Example 1 does seems to respond to changing screen width from what I can see.  Problem with flexbox is lack of support in <=IE9.  Third example works fine in all the widths equal exactly 100%.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes simple is the best. I would stick with the third alternative, but as you see you have to give a positive value for margin property.

I would use this solution for your problem:

HTML CODE

```
<div class="left blue">Left</div>
<div class="left green">middle</div>
<div class="left yellow">right</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 10px 2px;
 }

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
 }

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me, right-hand block wraps over to new line.